# Git gets stuck on writing objects

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am trying to `git push --all` and it just hangs on writing objects

```
10.0-final-project git:(master) ✗ git push --all
Counting objects: 134, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (129/129), done.
Writing objects:  32% (44/134), 321.56 MiB | 231.00 KiB/s
```

The 321.56 MiB and 231.00 KiB/s continues to go up.

I have tried using `git config --global http.postBuffer` and `git config --global sendpack.sideband false`

Nothing is working. What is the way to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you're trying to push 321MB of data to git, you're probably doing something wrong.  Do you have a `.gitignore`? Are you pushing things to the repository that might be better placed in a CDN / S3 bucket (images, videos, etc)?

Answer (score 15):

Looks like you have added a **HUGE** binary files or folder to GIT.

Its not something you should do with git.

If this is the case consider solutions like: [Git Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

[Another relative article](http://blog.jessitron.com/2013/08/finding-and-removing-large-files-in-git.html) can be found here with some sample code for cleaning the repo.

---

#### Step 1: Identify the large files.

> We need to search through all of the history to find the files that are good candidates for deletion. As far as I can tell, this is nontrivial, so here is a complicated command that lists the sum of the sizes of all revisions of files that are over a million bytes. Run it on a mac.

```
git rev-list master | while read rev; do git ls-tree -lr $rev | cut -c54- |     grep -v '^ '; done | sort -u | perl -e '
  while (<>) {
      chomp;
      @stuff=split("\t");
      $sums{$stuff[1]} += $stuff[0];
  }
  print "$sums{$_} $_\n" for (keys %sums);
 ' | sort -rn >> large_files.txt
```

#### Step 2: Remove them like they were never there.

This is the fun part. If large_files.txt is still in the same format as before, do this:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf `cat /full/path/to/large_files.txt |
    cut -d " " -f 2` ' --prune-empty <BRANCHES>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It kept getting stuck. When I saw your answer I realised forgot to ignore a huge file.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem. But the cause was the current user didn't have write permission to the destination dir.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue i was having. I created the bare git repo on my server while being root.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 -R filename                      // opens it right up :)

Comment: I was looking for this problem solution, but I had perceive that the problem was permission on Git folder.

If someone is having this problem, check this out.

Comment: solved it for me. copied repo back into place, didn't recursively change permissions (just the directory)

Answer (score 0):

**Background:** 
One of my peers had mistakenly uploaded a bunch of huge files and related changes which were generated by CocoaPods under Pods directory (yes usually it's git-ignored, but due to some path changes it's uploaded.). So what I tried was altering that last commit and trying to force update the remote branch.

It's uploading with poor upload speed just like it's shown in the OP's post description. Obviously, I was waiting giving it about 30 minutes thinking it will finish and I wasn't sure how big the change was as I couldn't check it before.

**What I did?** 
I simply stopped the uploading by tapping: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>and then retried `git push -f` (in my case it's a force update hence the flag `-f`)

And it worked swiftly and uploaded. Surprisingly there wasn't a huge upload size but 22MB.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue due to large files before (like in [CodeWizard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34601464/745776)), but I also recently ran into a frozen `push` which turned out to be because of the VPN I had running on my computer.

Once I turned off the VPN I was able to `push` to my Github repo no problem.

Answer (score -2):

**Recommended**
locate your hidden files and delete the `.git` file - mine was over 6gb